# Java CryptoCipher Doesn't consume all input bytes

Tags: java, encryption, apache-commons

I'm trying to convert from using Chilkat's proprietary decryption library to Apache's commons crypto.  I have 2 example encrypted inputs I'm working with.  The first is 16 bytes and the second is 96 bytes.  The first one works great, but on the second one the CryptoCipher doesn't appear to be consuming the last 16 bytes.

Here's some example code of the setup and decryption and the output:

```
   Properties properties = new Properties();
    CryptoCipher crypt = CryptoCipherFactory.getCryptoCipher("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", properties);
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

    byte[] hashedKeyBytes = digest.digest("SHARED_SECRET".getBytes(
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    MessageDigest ivDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

    byte[] ivBytes = ivDigest.digest("SHARED_SECRET".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    final SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(hashedKeyBytes, "AES");
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);

    crypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

    ByteBuffer encBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(enc.length);
    System.out.println("--" + enc.length);
    encBuffer.put(enc);
    encBuffer.flip();
    System.out.println("encln " + encBuffer.limit());

    ByteBuffer decoded = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bufferSize);
    CryptoCipher crypt = init();

    System.out.println("consume " + crypt.update(encBuffer, decoded));
    System.out.println("finish " + crypt.doFinal(encBuffer, decoded));
    decoded.flip(); 
    return asString(decoded);
```

This produces these 2 outputs for the 2 inputs:

Short input:

```
--16
encln 16
consume 0
finish 13
```

Long input:

```
--96
encln 96
consume 80
finish 3
```

As you can see it's only consuming 80 bytes out of the input...  Since the shorter input produces the correct output as compared to what Chilkat produced, I'm not sure where to approach this to get it to work with the longer input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number returned by `crypt.update()` and `crypt.doFinal(..)` is the number of bytes decrypted, not the number of bytes consumed by the operation. As your data is padded (or at least you specify it as **PKCS5Padded**), your encrypted data will always be a bit bigger than the decrypted version. With **PSCS5** and **AES** the padding will add 1 to 16 bytes of padding to the nearest multiplum of 16 bytes which is the block size of **AES**.

In the the first example your 13 bytes of clear data have 3 bytes of padding giving 16 bytes of encrypted data (or one full AES block). In the second example you have 83 bytes of clear data and 13 bytes of padding (giving 6 AES blocks of 16 bytes).

Comment: Hmmm... I wonder why the last characters are getting cut out of the end...  I'll spend some time confirming that the incoming byte array is correct.  Maybe it's somehow getting cut off when converting from a String to a byte[]...

Comment: Padding is added automatically when you encrypt, and removed automatically when you decrypt. If you decrypt a message of 16 bytes with 3 bytes of padding, you would only get 13 bytes of decrypted data.